# Removing duplicate files but ignoring certain lines (e.g. embedded timestamp)

Tags: files, duplicate

I have a bunch of gzipped text files. I am trying to remove duplicate files (using `fdupes`) but the problem is these files contain a line that has their timestamp in them, and the files are identical otherwise.

I'd like to be able to find duplicates, ignoring this line, but *not* remove the line from the files that I keep.

In my case the line is of the following form:

```
-- Dump completed on 2014-07-12 10:00:01
```

Right now I am using the following script, which works but removes the timestamp line from the kept files:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Remove timestamp line from all gzipped text files by temporarily unzipping
# them, removing the line then rezipping. Preserve file system timestamp.
for a in *.sql.gz ; do
    gunzip -c $a | sed -e 's/^-- Dump completed.*//g' | gzip -c -9 > temp.gz
    touch -r $a temp.gz
    mv temp.gz $a
done

# Duplicates can now be removed.
fdupes . -dN
```

I want to find a solution that doesn't involve modifying the original files, leaving the timestamp line in.

Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: Why do you insist to keep the timestamp in the file, if the file name is also the timestamp?

Comment: @Rabin I don't rely on file system information (names and timestamps) for important data, and it complicates processing in general as well (for example piping a file whose name is the sole source of a piece of information to another program loses the information).

Comment: you can try a file system which support dedup.